# How to make elements of Parent not intractable in Unity

Tags: unity-game-engine

I have an `GameObjects` that contains children in it. This element is `Unity.UI.Button`. Elements arranged like this:

[image: Arrangment of elements]

[image]

Player is `Unity.UI.Button`, Image is "D" and it is `Unity.UI.Image`, Cards are "50" in button and Trash is "1", they are `TextMesh Pro`. How to make interactable only Button and "50"? Thanks a lot in advance!

Comment: So there are two buttons which are player and cards? Cards button is '50', then what's player button?

Comment: @GeekyQuentin Player Button is round with blue border, “50” is text of this button

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can turn off checkbox "Raycast Target" in Image D

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).